# JAXB Unmarshaller replaces \t in XSD restriction pattern with a whitespace

Tags: regex, xsd, jaxb, sax, xerces

When parsing an XML file with JAXB I encounter a very strange behaviour. Google won't find anyone else who had exactly this problem before.

In my XSD file I got the following restriction pattern:

```xml
    <xsd:restriction base="xoev-lc:String.Latin">
        <xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="([^\n\r\t])*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
```

In my test XML file i got postal address with street "My Street" and I get a parsing error like this:

> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 53; cvc-pattern-valid: Wert "My Street" ist nicht Facet-gültig in Bezug auf Muster "([^\n\r ])*" für Typ "AdressBestandteilType".]

which means that this value is not facet-valid on the pattern. **Note that the \t in the pattern has been replaced by a whitespace!** My XML file is valid if I change the street to "MyStreet" without a whitespace.

Why does JAXB replace the tab with a whitespace? Any hints how to solve this without changing the XSD?

Comment: What if you replace `([^\n\r\t])*` with `[^\n\r]*`? I see a kind of a conflict here: you tell the engine to allow anything but linebreaks and tabs, but still want to preserve whitespace.

Comment: Another guess: tabs and newlines are usually removed (in the software I am using at least) inside attribute values (replaced with space, too). Try using literal `\r`, `\n` and `\t` inside the pattern: `<xsd:pattern value="([^\\n\\r\\t])*"/>`.

Comment: [^\n\r]* works fine, but tabs shall explicitly be declined! Preserving whitespace doesn't make a difference.

Comment: ([^\\n\\r\\t])* throws another SAXParseException, saying ([^\\n\\r\ ]) (again \t is replaced!) is not a valid regular expression.

Comment: I see. What if you replace `\t` in the pattern with `\x09`?

Comment: One solution is ([^\n\r&#x9;])* but since I'm not the owner of the XSD i am not allowed to change it.